# How to properly use '%' for escaping YAML configuration in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

When it comes to creating bundles, it's often necessary to support some [configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html) for the developers who'll use the bundle.

In this case, I need the configuration's value to support `%someText%`, without [Symfony trying to resolve this value as parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters).

**Example: Incorrect Configuration**

```yaml
my_bundle_name:
    my_configuration: '%someText%'
```

So, I figured, I'll have to escape the `%` (so it looks like `%%`) to make things work - resulting in the value `%%someText%%`.

> If some parameter value includes the % character, you need to escape it by adding another % so Symfony doesn't consider it a reference to a parameter name [...]

**Example: No Error, but Unexpected Result**

```yaml
my_bundle_name:
    my_configuration: '%%someText%%'
```

While this solves the `You have requested a non-existent parameter[...]` error, the actual value is now `%%someText%%`. I expected Symfony to return the *unsecaped* value instead, i.e., `%someText%`.

Sure I could `str_replace('%%', '%', '%%someText%%')`, but this feels hack-ish.

*How would I change the value to actually get `%someText%` instead?*

Here's where the configuration is loaded:

```php
// Namespace and use statements omitted for brevity
class MyBundleNameExtension extends ConfigurableExtension
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function loadInternal(array $mergedConfig, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('config.yml');

        p_r($mergedConfig["my_configuration"]); // Prints %%someText%%
    }
}
```

I've verified that using both `'` and `"` yields the same result.

Comment: How/where are you retrieving the value?

Comment: Hi, thanks, sometimes I forget that people don't magically know my code :-) I've updated the question :-)

Comment: mh ... just a thought, because symfony apparently distinguishes the two: have you tried using double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`? possibly won't work though ;o/ but apart from that, I agree this behavior is weird and unexpected. feels like a bug actually.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I've updated the question accordingly :-)

Comment: For me works fine to use `%%someText%%`, it transforms to `%someText%`

Comment: Interesting, which Symfony version are you using? :-)

Comment: Tried with 4.4 and 5

Comment: Thanks, I'm using 4.3.4 - I'll check again on a fresh install and if that doesn't help I'll try upgrading Symfony :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

The problem was that the `loadInternal` was called before the parameters were processed, thus, leaving me with `%%someText%%`.

#### The solution

I created a `SetupListener` class like so:

```php
<?php

// Namespace and use statements omitted

class SetupListener
{
    /** @var ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag */
    private $parameterBag;

    /** @var ContainerInterface $container */
    private $container;

    /**
     * SetupListener constructor.
     * @param ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->parameterBag = $parameterBag;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestEvent $event
     */
    public function onSetup(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        if($event->isMasterRequest() && !$event->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $var = $this->parameterBag->get("my_configuration");
            // Further processing...
        }
    }
}
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works for me.